# What is the difference between these two linker option tabs in the project Options dialog

Tags: linker, iar, build-definition

I am using the IAR Embedded Workbench IDE to build a project for an ARM processor. Looking at the project Options dialog, at the Linker category, two of the available tabs are **Config** and **#define**.

In the Config tab there is a space for defining Configuration file (icf) symbols. However, the #define tab seems to be doing the same. Is it really a duplicate functionality? If not, what am I missing?

From the help file, on the Config tab:

> **Configuration file symbol definitions**
>
> Define constant configuration symbols to be used in the configuration file. Such a
>   symbol has the same effect as a symbol defined using the define symbol
>   directive in the linker configuration file.

On the #define tab:

> **Defined symbols**
>
> Define absolute symbols to be used at link time. This
>   is especially useful for configuration purposes. Type the symbols that
>   you want to define for the project, one per line, and specify their
>   value.